# WS proxy for firewalled ActiveMQ server

Tags: tomcat, servlets, websocket, jms, activemq-classic

Is there a way for browser clients to connect via websockets through a Tomcat/Jetty server and pass JMS connections to an ActiveMQ server?

We would like to keep our JMS server behind the firewall but allow clients whom already connect to our Tomcat application server to connect to ActiveMQ via websockets thought the same host.

Answer (score 2):

JMS is a client side API, not a protocol.

Using the ActiveMQ JMS client, you will use OpenWire, which cannot be sent over websocket (without a major coding exercise). What you can do is to proxy one of the transports that actually work well with websockets - MQTT or STOMP.

I would recommend using some lightweight reverse proxy in front of both your web app (tomcat) and ActiveMQ. That could be Apache httpd or Nginx. Even without websockets, it's a good idea to protect your java server with some battle hardened web proxy.

I have done such a thing with the web server Nginx and MQTT over WebSocket and it works very well. Although I guess there is no difference for Stomp over WebSocket. The nice thing is that you can also easily terminate SSL in the proxy server, which is usually faster/easier than doing so in the app server.

This does not really help with using the JMS api at client side. Not sure if there is anything production ready out there. Skipping the JMS spec and use STOMP over Websocket clients should do it, though.

Sample Nginx config to proxy WebSocket (and terminate SSL/TLS in this case) to, say an ActiveMQ server.

```
upstream websocket {
    server example.com:61623;
}
server {
    listen 8883 ssl;
    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/bundle2015.cer;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/server2015.key;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://websocket;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade websocket;
        proxy_set_header Connection upgrade;
        proxy_read_timeout 120s;
    }
}
```